# how to trigger the download of a .txt file after logging into a site using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, authentication, download

Code used for logging in:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import urllib

payload = {       
   'email'    : 'xxx@gmail.com',
   'password' : 'xxx'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    m  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net',headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})   
    t  = s.post('https://www.free-ebooks.net',data = payload)
    r  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/The-Best-Scandal-Ever')
    print r.content
```

from the output of `print r.content`, i think my login was successful
code used for triggering the download:

```
<<<code same as above>>>
with requests.Session() as s:
   m  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net',headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})   
   t  = s.post('https://www.free-ebooks.net',data = payload)
   r  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/The-Best-Scandal-Ever')
   urllib.urlretrieve("https://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/The-Best-Scandal-Ever/txt", "myfile007.pdf")
```

In my output pdf i am getting the source code, and not the original contents of the pdf.
I have a feeling that i am supposed to use the instance of already started session.But dont know how to implement it.
ANY1?

Comment: How did you confirm that the login was successful? could you see the session id in `s.cookies` ? adding to @falsetru's answer, the actual url which triggers the text download is `../The-Best-Scandal-Ever/txt?dl` `..The-Best-Scandal-Ever/txt` simply opens up a web page that internally triggers the actual download

Answer (score 0):

`requests` and `urllib` are different. They don't share information (especially cookie).

Use `requests`' consistently.

```
with requests.Session() as s:
    m  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net', headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    t  = s.post('https://www.free-ebooks.net', data=payload)
    r  = s.get('https://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/The-Best-Scandal-Ever')
    resp = s.get("https://www.free-ebooks.net/ebook/The-Best-Scandal-Ever/txt",
                 stream=True)
    with open("myfile007.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.writelines(resp.iter_content())
```

Comment: nope , i tried the above code, still the source code is being stored into "myfile007".